# Other permalinks works but not %postname%

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

WordPress › Support » How-To and Troubleshooting

I have imported my site from mybb to WordPress 3.9.1 All seems to fine but when I change permalinks from numeric to %postname% some of the posts shows the permalink correctly i.e.

```
www.example.com/A-new-post
```

however some posts shows only the domain i.e. post number 2 shows

```
www.example.com
```

I Tried all permalink settings all seems to work except %postname% which infect works but only converts partial posts to permalinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My blog has too old posts over 2 years, so I need to open each post and its url converted to %postnum%